# What happens to derived object's data members when upcast?

Tags: java, inheritance

What happens to the derived class data members when its upcasted?
Say derived class was maintaining a big 500MB hashmap. When I upcast it to parent, does the upcast class object's size include 500MB?

```
ParentClass p = childObject;
```

where,

```
ChildClass childObject = new ChildClass();
```

and

```
public class ChildClass extends ParentClass{
    HashMap<int> bigHashmap;
}
```

does p include its own size plus the size of bigHashmap?
I then pass P as a constructor argument to another class which keeps it as a local member.

Comment: It's the same object.

Comment: The declared type has nothing to do with its actual type. If it's a `ChildClass` then it's a `ChildClass`, whether you've declared it as a `ParentClass` or not. Upcasting just restricts your access, it doesn't technically do anything.

Comment: What size are you referring to? Yes, the hashmap still exists even though that `p` maybe does not "know" about it. And there is no such thing as `sizeof(...)` in java. If you pass `p` around you pass the reference, the constructor could downcast again and get access to the big hashmap.

Comment: since p is just holding the address of childObject, there is'nt really any additional memory usage right? The process will store a single copy of bigHashmap as part of childObject and everyone else including parentClass just holds a reference (size = int) of childObject

Comment: If you're just declaring `Parent p = existingObject`, then no there's no real extra memory usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Casting an object does not change anything. At runtime, the object is still the same object at the same memory address. During compilation, casting is only using for checking which methods can be called and which not. During runtime, casting is using to determine if the object instance is compatible with a given type.

Comment: Not correct; [`checkcast`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se11/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.checkcast) is a JVM instruction and is used extensively at runtime.